# Get parameters from soap request

Tags: java, web-services, soap

my app receive a soap request; this is an example:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
    <ns1:authorize> 
            <params>AppSender</params> 
            <params>url.appsender.local</params> 
            <params>GET /applic/ HTTP/1.1</params> 
            <params>2017-01-4T09:38:00.601Z@NCODER08F839F@myapp.sch</params> 
            <params>/applic/</params> 
            <params>2.0.00</params> 
            <params></params> 
            <params>d1c714fe-cae1-4150-934f-bb3e61ad85f2</params> 
            <params>Authentication-Instant</params><params>2017-01-</params> 
            <params>fiscalCode</params><params>NTSDNT80R085454</params> 
            <params>userName</params><params>user</params> 
            <params>levelVerification</params><params>10</params> 
            <params>AuthenticationType</params><params>BASIC</params> 
    </ns1:authorize>
```

Can i have an example that i take this request and i set the value of the tag "params" in a JavaBean???

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must process the request with some java library for XML processing.

Example:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
doc =  builder.parse(request);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
org.w3c.dom.Node nodeRoot =  doc.getFirstChild();
if(nodeRoot.getNodeName().equals("authorize")) {  
                 ... doc.getElementsByTagName("params")...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JAXB, here you have more info ...
http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-in-eclipse-ide/